# OBIEE Characteristic Table with dynamic header

Tags: pivot-table, obiee

[image: Original Data]

I have original data as shown above with a single record. I have name of the field in one column and value in another column. I need to transform make the heading dynamic as shown below.

I tried with table pivot table and trellis, not no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in a pivot table in OBIEE.

Please see my below screenshot. I was able to get my column originally named 'Total Contracted Cases' to now be called 'USD' because that is the value in the column 'Currency Code'. So for you, you should be able to get the column 'PARAM_VAL1' to be called 'COUNTRY' because that is the value in the column 'PARAM_CD1'. See below for my example:

[image: Pivot Table]

[image: Pivot Table Details]

In the second image, be sure to click on the 'Measure Lables' properties to hide the value.

For columns that are not metrics (no aggregation rule set) that will be used in the 'Measures' section of the pivot table, you will have to define an aggregation rule in the column properties dialog box to keep the value from being converted to null. If your data is as you say it is (a single record), then this should not be an issue; you should be able to pick any aggregation rule and not have to worry about dropping data.